# Optimizing Checking for Words in a Dict and List

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, dictionary

I have the following code

```
for key,value in jobs.items():
    job = key
    jobVector[key] = []
    for x in range (0, len(listOfWords)):
        if listOfWords[x] in jobs[job]:
            jobVector[key].append(1)
        else:
             jobVector[key].append(0)
```

I have a dict, JOBS which has various words stored and a count for each. The count is irrelevant in this case, but lets say jobs is like this for one of the keys:

```
jobs[1] = account, addit, allow, ascertain, associ, avail, career, cellular, chang, coasttocoast, commiss, compani, competit, comput, countri, coupl, credit, custom, demand, develop, driven, dynam, employ, enjoi, ethic, exist, expand, experienc, fastest, flexibl, greet, growth, highperform, independ, individu, internet, knowledg, maintain, market, monitor, opportun, order, outstand, payment, person, phone, place, price, privatelyown, process, product, profession, provid, purchas, pursu, receiv, recommend, repres, resolv, respons, retail, right, selfmotiv, specif, store, support, technolog, territori, thatll, throughout, total, train, uniqu, unpreced, wireless, account, addit, aptitud, avail, bartend, benefit, bestbui, bilingu, cellular, colleg, commiss, commun, comput, consult, cross, custom, dedic, deduct, dental, direct, disabl, discount, effect, enterpris, entir, entrepreneuri, excel, execut, extend, famili, fleet, flexibl, goalori, health, impress, individu, insid, insur, integr, interperson, keyword, liter, longterm, medic, member, negoti, offer, outsid, packag, period, person, pleas, possess, possibl, pound, prefer, prescript, proud, provid, recogn, rentacar, repres, respons, retail, retir, salesman, salesperson, saleswoman, satisfi, shield, shortterm, spanish, spend, spirit, sprint, stand, technic, therefor, tmobil, vehicl, verbal, visit, websit, wireless, wwwjoincellularsalescom
```

lets say listOfWords is like this:

```
listOfWords = associ, avail, career, cellular, chang, coasttocoast, commiss, compani, competit, comput, countri, coupl, credit, custom, demand, develop, driven, dynam, employ, enjoi, ethic
```

I pretty much want to go through each word in the listOfWords and see if it exists in the individual job for each job in the JOBS dict. If it exists, store a 1, else store a 0 into another dictionary.

Is their any way to speed this up? It currently works, but takes about 3 minutes on a dataset of 15000 jobs.

Comment: Whenever possible, replace lists with sets.  Sets can membership test (i.e. `if something in some_set`) rapidly.  Lists have to go through every element one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can speed things up a bit by replacing all those lists of jobs with sets of jobs. The code you've shown us then won't have to change at all, it'll just magically get faster, because an `in` test for a set is nearly instant, while an `in` test for a list has to check every value in the list.

---

You can also get some small speedups—and a big readability gain—by replacing the `range` loop with a direct loop, using `value` instead of re-looking it up, and turning the whole loop into a comprehension:

```
for key, value in jobs.items():
    jobVector[key] = [1 if word in value else 0 for word in listOfWords]
```

Or even:

```
jobVector = {
    key: [1 if word in value else 0 for word in listOfWords]
    for key, value in jobs.items() }
```

Also, if this is for Python 2.x, use `viewitems` (if you don't need 2.6 or earlier) or `iteritems` (if you do) instead of `items`.

---

But really, beyond using a list in place of a set, I suspect there's a bigger problem with your data structures. Without knowing what you're trying to use these things for, it's hard to be sure, but I suspect you could make things both clearer and faster by using another dictionary, keyed off the individual jobs, so you can look them up instantly instead of exhaustively searching.

If each individual job can belong to only one job (your terminology here is really confusing, by the way…), this is just a dict mapping each individual job to its parent:

```
d = {ijob: job for job, ijobs in jobs.items() for ijob in ijobs}
```

If each individual job can belong to multiple jobs, you need to map each to the set of jobs it belongs to:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(set)
for job, ijobs in jobs.items():
    for ijob in jobs:
        d[ijob].add(job)
```

Then it seems like you don't really even need `jobVector` for anything, because it'll be as fast to look up its elements on the fly as to use the values you're precomputing.